# How do I add a new block to my layout in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento

I have a beginner question on layouts ...After reading a lot about layouts, i am more confused than where i started. I want to add a banner block that will be displayed on my home page and a few other pages.  I decided that it cannot be a part of the header.

I want to add this right below the header. I am trying to create my layout via bootstrap. I see in some themes that this is done inside the cms.xml file and i am not sure why i need to edit that. Clearly, i am confused..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your theme

```
app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/layout/local.xml
```

add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <cms_index_index>
      <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="banner" before="-"  template="banner/banner.phtml" />
        </reference>
   </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

add banner.phtml file to

```
app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/banner/banner.phtml
```

add your banner in above file

To add a block to any other page replace `<cms_index_index>` with `<routname_controllername_actionname>` For example, `<catalog_product_view>`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, one follow up question i would have is, in case i want to add this to any other page (not just the home page) what would be reference to which i would add it? I understand cms_index_index is only for the home page.

Comment: `<routname_controllername_actionname></routname_controllername_actionname>` as an example `<catalog_product_view></catalog_product_view>` this reference for catalog product view page